# jar file with arguments in docker

Tags: java, docker, dockerfile

Helo,

I have a java .jar file that takes a bunch of arguments as input when i run it from the terminal.I want to make a docker image and run it that contains the jar file where i can still pass the arguments for the jar file.

Comment: Have you already created a docker container? Your container can inherit by a container with java. Just copy your jar file on it and you can use it as on your local machine. Where do you struggle exactly? Stack Overflow is not there to solve you everything you could read up easily...

Answer (score 9):

Set the jar file as your [entrypoint](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#/entrypoint) and the args as your [command](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#/cmd)

An example:

```
ENTRYPOINT ["/path/to/my/java.jar"]
CMD ["my", "default", "args"]
```

You can then override the args whenever you run the container, using:

```
docker run <my-docker-image> some custom args
```

More information here: http://goinbigdata.com/docker-run-vs-cmd-vs-entrypoint/

Comment: although the comment seems very logical , i am having error when running the image as no such file or directory despite setting the path of the jar correctly.Thnks for your help!

Comment: Then you need to add your dockerfile to the question, as there's no enough information here to solve your problem

Comment: It is very old, but his question is very clear as well. We just want do it `java -jar -Dargs1... app.jar`. I want the same, but dynamic it doesn't work. XD
When I say dynamic. I am talking about `ENV JAVA_ARGS` as `CMD java -jar $JAVA_ARGS app.jar`.

Comment: The 'exec' form of ENTRYPOINT doesn't support variable expansion so I'd use the 'shell' form of ENTRYPOINT instead for what you want to do. Like so:
ENV JAVA_OPTS "-XX:+UseG1GC -XX:+UseContainerSupport"
ENTRYPOINT exec java ${JAVA_OPTS} -jar /app/app.jar