# Docker and setting JVM parameters

Tags: java, docker, jvm

I need to run Java application in the Docker container with JVM options like these, but I have no idea where I can set it, I've tried use "java -Dcom...." command but it doesn't work. What is the best way to do this?

-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.rmi.port=9090

-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote=true

-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=9090

-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false

-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false

-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.local.only=false

-Djava.rmi.server.hostname=192.168.99.100

Comment: Check this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41185591/jar-file-with-arguments-in-docker

Answer (score 3):

If you are running with docker-compose.yml file you should add then under the specific docker entry, 
for example:

```
docker-name:

    extends:

      file: ...
      service: ...

    image: ...
    ports:
      - "9090:9090"
    environment:
      component_type: ...
      instance_id: ...
    JAVA_OPTS: "
        -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.rmi.port=9090

        -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote=true

        -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=9090

        -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false

        -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false

        -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.local.only=false

        -Djava.rmi.server.hostname=localhost"

    volumes:
       - ...
     ..
```

..
   ..

Comment: JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS appears to be more reliable for different types of JVM than JAVA_OPTS.
CLASSPATH and possibly SPRING_APPLICATION_JSON are also very useful environment variables to pass options to java without modifying the run command within the image.

Answer (score 0):

To pass JVM arguments to a Spring Boot application I have used the following:

`mvn spring-boot:run -Dspring-boot.run.jvmArguments="-Xdebug -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=9010 -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.rmi.port=9010 -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false -Djava.rmi.server.hostname=localhost"`

I have a docker-compose service to specifically profile my application using something like VisualVM (which looks like you are also trying to do something similar) as I do not always want to use these configurations:

```
version: '3.7'
services:
  profile:
    image: my_base_image
    container_name: my_container_name
    ports:
      - '8081:8080'
      - '9010:9010'
    volumes:
      - './src:/build/src
      - './target:/build/target'
      - './logs:/build/logs'
      - './pom.xml:/build/pom.xml'
    command: 'mvn spring-boot:run -Dspring-boot.run.jvmArguments="-Xdebug -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=9010 -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.rmi.port=9010 -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false -Djava.rmi.server.hostname=localhost"'
```

I simply run this to start it up:
`docker-compose up profile`

I have written about this topic if you want to read the entire article:

https://blog.phillipninan.com/2020/08/19/diagnose-memory-leaks-in-spring-boot-with-visual-vm/

Answer (score -1):

Here my example for you:

```
CMD java -Xmx1024m -Xms512m -Dserver.port=8080 -jar mywar.war
```

Also if you have a lot of properties to add here it will be the best to create the file with environment variables. And load them to the container. And in your application use env variables to generify your app.

Comment: so, similarly CMD java -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.rmi.port=9090 should work? Becaouse it doesn't.